# In JavaScript, is it frowned upon to use the '==' operator?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript === vs == : Does it matter which “equal” operator I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

Noticed this

> == is bad. Don’t ever use it. On everything else about the language, you’ll run into differing opinions.

...while reading an article I found on Hacker News: http://duruk.net/some-web-development-tips/

Why is this frowned upon? What are the alternatives? Is this wrong...

```
if (foo == bar) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, it's better to use `===` and `!==`.  These compare type and value and do not do type conversion.

Whereas `==` will do a type conversion of one to match the other and then do the comparison so it might report equality on things that are not really the same.

For example:

```
"0" == 0   // true
"0" === 0  // false
```

Comment: Thank you! Will answer in 11 mins.